# Dynamically get an Ethereum node

Tags: ethereum

I'm writing a web application using Ethereum at the moment and realize only now that I have to specific a web3.provider's IP address to tap into the blockchain.

If I have to specify an IP address, how are web apps. (dApps) considered decentralized?

I recognize the data may be ... but the utility of the dApp itself is null if the user doesn't have a frontend tap.

So my question is, from a technical perspective, how do I dynamically grab an IP address to an Ethereum node w/o using some sort of centralized DNS platform?

ENS (the Ethereum Name Service) appears to work similarly to centralized DNS platforms as you need a resolver to get the resource.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to know is that you should not connect your dapp to an IP. You and ever other user will are supposed to connect to a different node. So, it is the user who will connect to a node. The user will be connect to a local or remote node of his/here choice. For you as a developer, when you will be sure that any user connected to a healthy node, he will be using the same version of the dapp.

Note: local nodes can be Geth and Parity nodes connected to main-net. And remote nodes can be the nodes that MetaMask connects to (MetaMask uses infura.io).

Note: If you will force your users to connect to a specific IP, you cannot call your app 'decentralized'.